# Voting theory when NO is an option

Tags: reference-request, voting-theory

Has anyone mathematically studied voting systems in which NO is one of the options, or more precisely in which one of the possible outcomes is that none of the candidates win?  If so, where can I read about them?

One possible way to design such a voting system is to simply include NO as one of the candidates and use any ordinary voting system.  But there are other ways one might imagine designing such a system, and I'd like to know whether any of them has advantages (or disadvantages).

Comment: This has been explored by Richard Pryor as a _None of the above_ choice in "Brewster's Millions": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXEglx-or6k

Comment: Those are pretty different things, making the question rather broad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_the_above  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disapproval_voting

Comment: @Michael I don't see any mathematics there.

Comment: @endolith Disapproval voting doesn't look to me like it satisfies my description, at least not how it is described on wikipedia.  But if it does, then a comparison of it to other options (no matter how different) would be an answer to the question.